# summing time column in mysql

Tags: mysql, time

I have a column in one of my tables, which is TIME format (00:00:00). I am trying to sum the entire column and display it as same (00:00:00).

I have tried using the following but it is not giving me anywhere near the correct answer.It's giving me 22.12:44:00 and manual calcaulation tells me it should be close to 212:something:something

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `vluchttijd` ) ) )  AS totaltime FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens

Any recommendations?

Comment: That logic seems sound. Can you post specific data that appears to fail? And can you clarify the output? That doesn't look to be in quite the right format.

Comment: all of the data in the table appears correct. Nothing appears to out of order or causing any kind of failure from what I can tell.  sample data includes: 
09:00:00, 01:00:00, 07:50:00, 12:00:00, 08:30:00, 00:45:00, 12:10:00 - these values alone should be much higher even than what I am getting.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:-

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SECOND(vluchttijd ))) AS totaltime FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens;
```

or try this(althoug this is not a good approach):

```
SELECT concat(floor(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `vluchttijd ` ))/3600),":",floor(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `vluchttijd ` ))/60)%60,":",SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `vluchttijd ` ))%60) AS total_time 
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens;
```

**Edit:-**

Try this:-

```
select  cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' + 
        right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +
        ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))%60 as varchar(2)),2)
from    TestTable
```

Working [SQL Fidlle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23503/2)

Comment: this yields a 0:00:00 result. hmmm.

Comment: i get 0:0:0 as the result.

Comment: With both the queries? In that case please tell the datatype of your column.

Comment: the datatype is TIME for this column

Comment: I have updatd my answer with a working SQL Fiddle. Please check.

Comment: in toad I get: Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datefiff' 
when I put it into PHP I get: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /.../.../.../vluchtgegevens/stats/index.php on line 198

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the [`TIME` type is rather limited in range](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html). Moreover many time function do not accept values greater that `23:59:59`, making it really usable only to represent the *time of the day*.

Given your needs, your best bet is probably to write a custom function that will mimic [`SEC_TO_TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) but allowing much greater range:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SEC_TO_BIGTIME(sec INT)
RETURNS CHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @h = sec DIV 3600;
    SET @m = sec DIV 60 MOD 60;
    SET @s = sec MOD 60;

    RETURN CONCAT(
          LPAD(@h, 4, '0'),
          ':',
          LPAD(@m, 2, '0'),
          ':',
          LPAD(@s, 2, '0')
      );

END;
```

And here is how to use it:

```
create table tbl (dt time);
insert tbl values
  ('09:00:00'), ('01:00:00'), ('07:50:15'), ('12:00:00'), 
  ('08:30:00'), ('00:45:00'), ('12:10:30');

select SEC_TO_BIGTIME(sum(time_to_sec(dt))) from tbl;
```

Producing:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_BIGTIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DT))) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 0051:15:45                           |
+--------------------------------------+
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/aaab8/1

Please note the result is a `CHAR(10)` in order to overcome `TIME`type limitations. Depending how you plan to use that result, that means that you may have to convert from that string to the appropriate type in your host language.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(vluchttijd))) AS totaltime FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens;
```